# Stash: How can I get the 'url_title' of the first channel entry?

Tags: stash

I am not very used to stash.
My code looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="moebel" 
    orderby="date" 
    sort="desc" 
    dynamic="off" 
    disable="member_data|trackbacks|pagination"
}
    <a href="{path=moebel/{url_title}}" {if url_title == '{segment_2}' OR segment_2 == '' AND count == '1'}class="active"{/if} >{count}</a>

{if count == '1'}
    {exp:stash:set name="myurltitle"}{url_title}{/exp:stash:set}
{/if}                   
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This does not work because the variable 'myurltitle' will always be the last url_title of the 10 entries in the channel.

How can I realize this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [Switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee), which is perfect for use with Stash and probably good for opening bottles and cans of Tuna as well:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="moebel"
}
    {exp:switchee variable="{count}" parse="inward"}
        {case value="1"}
            {exp:stash:set name="myurltitle"}{url_title}{/exp:stash:set}
        {/case}
    {/exp:switchee}                  
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Or the `{exp:ifelse}` add-on works like Swtichee. Both IfElse and Switchee are from the same developer as Stash, and they all play nicely together.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to using stash myself. Try putting the stash in its own channel loop, with a limit of one entry.

Compare "Basic Example" on this page: https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aset%7D

```
// One entry to stash your info here - and ONLY the stash info. 
{exp:channel:entries channel="moebel" 
    orderby="date" 
    sort="desc" 
    dynamic="off" 
    disable="member_data|trackbacks|pagination"
    limit="1"
    }
    {exp:stash:set name="myurltitle"}{url_title}{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}

// The primary loop for everything else here

{exp:channel:entries channel="moebel" 
    orderby="date" 
    sort="desc" 
    dynamic="off" 
    disable="member_data|trackbacks|pagination"
    }
    <a href="{path=moebel/{url_title}}" {if url_title == '{segment_2}' 
    OR segment_2 == '' AND count == '1'}class="active"{/if} >{count}</a>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Also, your last if check **{if url_title == '{segment_2}' OR segment_2 == '' AND count == '1'}** could use some parentheses for better operation, e.g. **{if url_title == '{segment_2}' OR (segment_2 == '' AND count == '1')}**